# Source of a load torque

Tags: motors, torque

I am currently taking a course titled "Electric machinery and drives". We have started with the very basics, i.e with the following equation:

$\tau_{motor} = \tau_{load} + \frac{\partial (J\omega_m)}{\partial t}$

where, $\tau$ is the notation for torque and $J$ is the notation for "polar moment of inertia, $\omega_m$ being the angular velocity of the motor shaft.

My question is: what is the source of the load torque $\tau_{load}$?, i.e is there some external agency that tries to rotate the shaft in the opposite direction?

On a side note, please also explain what the equation simplifies to if the load is just simply a massive flywheel

Answer (score 1):

The load torque is from what you want the motor to power or drive be it a saw or conveyor or drill which, depending on the process, may vary.

For example, the load can change on a conveyor depending on the amount of material to be moved - keep increasing the material and the load increases.

Comment: But sir, hasn't that been taken into account by the angular momentum term in the equation?

Comment: So what is the torque term for then?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that moment of inertia terms is that of the rotating parts of *the motor itself*, note that it disappears when angular velocity is constant.

It doesn't make much sense to model the external load on the motor as a moment of inertia as many common types of load are essentially friction of one sort of another.